# I just started coding in lua-roblox, and I face attempt to index nil with 'Value, and can't find out why

Tags: lua, roblox

So I just started Lua in roblox and I can't find out why am I facing this error (code below)

> Workspace.Script:11: attempt to index `nil` with `'Value'`

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    currency = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    currency.Name = "oil"
    currency.Value = 100
    return 0
end)

while true do
    currency.Value = 100+10 -- here would be the problem
    wait(5)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to put the `while true` loop inside of `Players.PlayerAdded` to have it work well.

---

Side Note: Instead of using

```lua
local stats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
```

you should use

```lua
local stats = Instance.new("Folder")
stats.Parent = player
```

as this runs much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The `PlayerAdded:Connect(function ... end)` means you're setting up a function now to be called later when a player joins the game. It doesn't get run right away.

Immediately after that, the script goes to your `while` loop. But `currency` hasn't been set to anything yet, so its value is just `nil`, making `currency.Value` invalid.

Also, you have the `currency` global variable set whenever a player joins. Meaning if it is set, it will be the statistic value for the last one player to join, and any code outside the `PlayerAdded` callback would only be changing things for that one player.

Comment: This is why globals are evil. I wish the'd just start every Lua tutorial with that sentence.

Comment: @aschepler Even if I join the game and get the currency right amount in my stats I still face the error, I thought at it not being created before while loop, but if I have the stats it means that it's another problem, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You've tried something else in code? Or you're noting that this does set up an "oil" value? The callback function is still okay, but I'm guessing you always see a value of 100, not 110.

Comment: The value of oil never gets increased because of Workspace.Script:11: attempt to index nil with 'Value' at the line 11, and I can't figure why. On the comment above I meant that even if the player (myself) joins and the folder and the value gets created I face the error. I'm sorry I know that I used global values and my work is bad, but right now I'm just learning and I really want to understand why this error occurs

Comment: 1. The function at the top gets connected to the `PlayerAdded` event. 2. The script hits the error in the while loop, and stops permanently. 3. A player connects, and the `PlayerAdded` function does get called. It creates the `currency` global and shows oil:100 on the player's screen. But there's nothing to ever change it.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a object that doesn't exist. The 'Currency' object is nil basically, to fix it basically put the while true loop in it. It shows the error if you index (go to a object using a period).

**Fixed Code**

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    currency = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    currency.Name = "oil"
    currency.Value = 100
    return 0

   while true do
    currency.Value = 100 + 10 -- Should be here
    wait(5)
end

end)
```